# Drafts rendered by netlify when draft: true in yaml

Tags: r, rstudio, hugo, blogdown, netlify

I am running at blogdown site from this [github repo](https://github.com/tmastny/website2) hosted by Netlify at https://timmastny.rbind.io/

In website2/content/blog/ I have two posts

[2018-01-16-git-blogdown-project-workflow.Rmd](https://github.com/tmastny/website2/blob/master/content/blog/2018-01-16-git-blogdown-project-workflow.Rmd)

and
[2018-01-13-bayesian-meta-analysis-powerlifting.Rmd](https://github.com/tmastny/website2/blob/master/content/blog/2018-01-13-bayesian-meta-analysis-powerlifting.Rmd)

You can see that in the YAML of both posts, I have `draft: true` and in the second one I even have `publishdate: '2018-01-20'` which is in the future as of this post.

However, with these changes pushed to github and Netlify deployed with a clean cache, on my actual website I still see the posts:
https://timmastny.rbind.io/

What am I missing about `draft: true`?

I've read sections 2.3.1 and D.3 of the books, but I'm not sure. I've also updated Hugo to 0.32.4 and am on the latest version of blogdown.

---

Edit: I've deleted the `public` folder and added `public` to gitignore. Netlify had a 16 minute build which was published. But on the actual website I get a **Page Not Found** error.

Here's the log: https://app.netlify.com/sites/timmastny/deploys/5a60c299df99532a0147c3d7

Here's my deploy settings on Netlify. They should match the suggestions in 3.1 of the blogdown book:

> Deploy settings
>
> Repository: https://github.com/tmastny/website2
>
> Build command: hugo
>
> Publish directory: public
>
> Production branch: master
>
> Branch deploys: Deploy only the production branch and its deploy previews
>
> Public deploy logs: Logs are public
>
> Build environment variables:
>   HUGO_VERSION 0.32.4

Comment: I answered your question, but deleted it because I am not sure how you are deploying to Netlify. If you delete your public folder and rebuild, the posts still show up locally? Are you running the build command on Netlify or just local then committing them into your public folder for deploy on Netlify?

Comment: @talves I'm reasonably sure your answer is actually correct. Tim should ignore `public` in `.gitignore` as recommended in https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/version-control.html

Comment: Definitely an issue if he is building without cleaning out the public folder first, but I was not sure he did not have other issues with his build. I will leave my answer until then.

Comment: @tmastny Updated answer for the next issue based on your update.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am going to assume you are using `public` as your deploy folder for Netlify.

### Issue #1

Your public folder is in your repository, so it is checked out to the Netlify site and when you run your build your posts already exist in that folder, so they are always going to be deployed.

### Solution #1

Delete the public folder from your project and add a `.gitignore` for the public folder.

The deploy should build the public folder fresh on each deploy, so it can compare the CDN with your build and copy the correct files only.

### Issue #2 (updated question)

The Hugo theme is set to `theme = "hugo-xmin"` in the `config.toml`. When checking out the repository from GitHub, this theme folder is empty. It would be empty on Netlify as well, so the build becomes invalid.

### Solution #2

Changed to a valid theme `theme = "hugo-lithium-theme"` in the `config.toml` and the build starts to create your site pages.

### Original Issue

When updating `draft: true` in `.Rmd` does not ignore on build.

### Solution (for Original)

Hugo is not processing your content for `.Rmd`, it is using your content from the processed `.html` files created. So you need to make sure you are committing the content for those files with `draft: true` in them to your repository before a build.

Comment: @Yihui Xie See my edit for an update. I've deleted public from my Github repo. Netlify still builds the website, but I get a **Page Not Found** error when I visit it.

Comment: @tmastny I made the update answer to your question update, Now looking at your original issue of `draft: true`

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem. For reference, instead of `git submodule add ...` the theme hugo-xmin, I knew I wanted to customize it and didn't care about keeping it attached to the main repo. So I just `git clone ...`. But since it was inside my website repo, it didn't automatically track it. So I needed to `git rm --cached -r themes/hugo-xmin` to make it local, then `add/commit/push` to track it within my website repo.

Thanks for all the help!