# Website not updating with blogdown & hugo

Tags: r, rstudio, hugo, blogdown, netlify

I know this question is likely to get down-voted due to insufficient reproducibility of code leading to the error, but I am so dumbfounded by the error I do not even know where to start in explaining it clearly enough. I therefore apologise in advance.

This issue has occurred twice on two separate machines. I created a new site with blogdown in R-Studio using the hugo-academic theme

```
new_site(theme = "gcushen/hugo-academic")
```

Everything works fine, and I start adding some publications (as markdown documents) by adding these to the /content/publication folder. This works just fine; the site looks fine via both `serve_site()` and `build_site()` (which linked via my GitHub repo updates my Netlify page just fine (https://jimgrange.netlify.com/)

However, this is all OK until I reach about 6-9 publications in my folder. Then, on two separate occasions, the site stops updating. No matter what I change in my code,  `serve_site()` and `build_site()` return the same (unchanged) site.

To try and solve this, I cloned the GitHub repository onto a different machine and served the website from there, but the same thing happened. Even though I have updated the markdown files in the website folders, nothing updates when I run `serve_site()` and `build_site()`. For example, if I change the "Your details" section of the config.toml file (line 42 here: https://github.com/JimGrange/website/blob/master/config.toml) nothing changes.

My website code is on my GitHub repo here:https://github.com/JimGrange/website

Again, I apologise for the poorly-formed question, but I am not sure how to approach a solution.

Best wishes,
Jim.

Comment: Can you tell us what your Netlify build command and the folder for deploy?

Comment: I have it building automatically from my GitHub repo from the public folder. That has been working just fine.  Im not sure it is a Netlify issue as it won't update in the R-Studio viewer when I use the bookdown command serve_site().

Comment: I'd concur that if it doesn't work locally it is not a Netlify problem.  Is there some way to verbosify running locally so you can see what is being processed on the way to serving the stale content?  Hugo at least has a "-v" which gives (a bit) more info as it builds the site.

Comment: Hmmm...I am not sure I follow. I am doing this from within R-Studio using the "serve_site()" function.

Comment: True. There must be something wrong with his R build. I am still concerned that not using the Hugo build will eventually cause unwanted side affects when deploying Hugo from the public folder. Blogdown recommends not storing public in the repo and building Hugo off of the processed files. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48312933/drafts-rendered-by-netlify-when-draft-true-in-yaml?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: Here is the blogdown recommendation https://bookdown.org/yihui/blogdown/version-control.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had exactly the same issue. Based on gchushen's suggestion (https://github.com/gcushen/hugo-academic/issues/517) I installed Hugo and ran `hugo -v` in the site folder. I had a typo in a publication markdown file that kept the website from building but R wasn't throwing an error. If you run `hugo -v` it should tell you which markdown file in your publications folder is giving the error.

Comment: Had the same issue, syntax error in a .md file  yaml header and the site stopped updating without an error message. Running hugo manually showed the error, but the site had kept getting served from the html built before the error was introduced. Seems like it would be useful to have more verbose error logging in the default blogdown configuration.

Comment: is hugo maybe never really throwing errors? Seems like I have to check after every comma I change if it still works! Now I worked for half an hour and changed some things and I have NO CLUE why nothing is changing anymore when I build or serve site!