# My hugo website made by blogdown does not update

Tags: hugo, blogdown

my question is a continuation of [Website not updating with blogdown & hugo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48647839/website-not-updating-with-blogdown-hugo)

After type `hugo -v` in my terminal:

[image: error]

I don't know how to find "&\" in the template

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked the content with a different theme? You know you can have several themes installed and just switch between them in `config.toml`. Then you will see if it is the problem with template or not.

Comment: Thanks r0berts! I have already solved this issue.It was a problem with _cache_ or something like that. I deleted the _html_ reports and I rerun. Problem solved :D

Comment: I just cleared the cache and it started to work again! This question could be closed.